# Rails - How do I change my custom methods in a controller to conventional methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a `Subscribers Controller` with custom methods like `add_subscribers`, `add_subscriber` and `remove_subscriber`.

How to I change these methods to using the conventional `create` and `destroy` methods to perform the same operations done in my custom methods?

`app/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb`

````
  def add_subscribers
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    authorize @group, :create?

    @course = @group.course    
    @student_subscribers = @course.subscribers
      .where("group_id !=? or group_id is null", @group.id)
  end

  def add_subscriber
    group = Group.find(params[:id])
    authorize group, :create?

    subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:subscriber_id])
    subscriber.group = group

    if subscriber.save
      flash[:alert] = "Successfully added!"
      redirect_to add_subscribers_group_path(group)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Failed to add user!"
      redirect_to add_subscribers_group_path(group)
    end
  end

  def remove_subscriber
    group = Group.find(params[:id])
    authorize group, :create?

    subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:subscriber_id])
    subscriber.group = nil

    if subscriber.save
      flash[:alert] = "Successfully removed!"
      redirect_to group
    else
      flash[:error] = "Failed to remove from group!"
      redirect_to group
    end
  end  
end```


I want to use the conventional methods to perform these operations instead of the custom methods. How can I do that?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it can be inferred that subscribers is nested resource under groups:

```
resources :groups do
  resources :subscribers
end
```

This will produce routes like `/groups/:group_id/subscribers/:id`

`remove_subscriber` maps exactly to `destroy` action (`delete` http verb), but you'll have to change id params - there'll be `params[:group_id]` and `params[:id]` is is of subscriber

`add_subscribers` probably renders the form, so it's the `new` action

`add_subscriber` is `create`

Answer (score 0):

In your config/routes file:

```
resources :subscribers
```

This will create the standard routes for that resource, and route them through the subscribers controller. You now need to rename your methods to `create`, `update` etc.. in your controller.

Finally if you were hitting these end points through a form, you'll need to edit that so that it points to the correct routes.

Once you've added the above line to your routes.rb, run `rake routes` from terminal to get a decent list of all your routes